# In a LINQ query, when calling ToDictionary, what is assigned the key and value?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var products =
(
    from p in products
    where !p.parentID.HasValue
    select new ProductList
    {
        Name = p.Name,
        Id = p.ID,
        IsInStock = products.Any(...)
    }           
)
.ToArray();
```

I want to call `ToDictionary()` and have the Id as the Key, and IsInStock as the value.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of using `ToDictionary()` that might help

```
var x = new[]
{
    new { Name = "Alice", Score = 50 },
    new { Name = "Bob", Score = 40 },
    new { Name = "Cathy", Score = 45 }
};

var y = x.ToDictionary(i => i.Name);
```

The value of y is (from LinqPad):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhvZX.png]

In any case, I think if you add `ToDictionary(a => a.ID, b => b.IsInStock)` you should get what you're looking for.

Comment: Where did you get that nice looking "inspector"?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var products =
(
    from p in products
    where !p.parentID.HasValue
    select new ProductList
    {
        Name = p.Name,
        Id = p.ID,
        IsInStock = products.Any( ... )
    }
)
.ToDictionary(y => y.ID, x => x.IsInStock);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you even try to write it??

I think little look at InteliSense would tell you there is simple override to ToDictinary, that takes selectors for both key and value : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx